# What is the meaning of 在经营销售上?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

在经营销售上，微信针对不同的国家和地区，推出了不同的广告片，邀请当地明星和名人代言，收效相当不错。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 12.

What is the meaning of 在经营销售上?

At the moment I am here:

在经营销售上 = 在［经营销售］上 = in managing / operating selling

What means managing selling or operating selling?

Baidu translate: In terms of operation and sales

Google translate: In terms of business sales

Where these translation engines found the word "terms"?

In any case, I cannot understand what this sentence mean.

Answer (score 2):

在 经营(和)销售 上 - On operation and marketing

Answer (score 1):

"In terms of" means "talking about", "Regarding", "As far as XX is concerned"

terms are words.

Chinese doesn't really distinguish verbs and nouns, so if you think 经营 means operate, a verb, well, it may just be operation(s), a noun, likewise 销售.

在经营销售上，
As far as operations and sales are concerned,
微信针对不同的国家和地区，
WeChat targets different countries and regions,
推出了不同的广告片，
has released various advertising videos,
邀请当地明星和名人代言，
(and) invited local stars and personalities (to be their) spokesmen and spokeswomen,
收效相当不错。
the results are quite good.

好好学习天天向上！